# Spring Boot - manually run flyway before anything else (failure to initialize entityManagerFactory)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, flyway

I'm having issues with getting flyway to play well with hibernate. I used to have the standard flyway settings, and it would run first on app startup. Great, exactly what I wanted.

Hibernate settings has `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none`

I then changed my main application to run flyway explicitly (because I want to conditionally run flyway in certain scenarios):

```
@Configuration
public class EmptyMigrationStrategyConfig {

    @Bean
    public FlywayMigrationStrategy flywayMigrationStrategy() {
        return flyway -> {
            // do nothing
        };
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {R2dbcAutoConfiguration.class})
@Configuration
@EnableRetry
public class MainApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private Flyway flyway;
    @Autowired
    private ShutdownManager shutdownManager;

    @Value("#{new Boolean('${app.migrations-only}')}")
    boolean migrationsOnly;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        flyway.migrate();
        if (migrationsOnly) {
            shutdownManager.initiateShutdown(0);
        }
    }
}
```

But now if I create a new migration script and add a POJO for an entity, the app fails to boot because hibernate is failing since flyway is no longer running first.

```
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: <entity> at <table>
```

What do I need to define so things run in the proper order?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so the actual issue ended up being a typo in the hibernate model... regardless this is how you'd get flyway to run explicitly first:

```
@Configuration
public class EmptyMigrationStrategyConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ShutdownManager shutdownManager;

    @Value("#{new Boolean('${app.migrations-only}')}")
    boolean migrationsOnly;

    @Bean
    public FlywayMigrationStrategy flywayMigrationStrategy() {
        return flyway -> {
            flyway.migrate();
            if (migrationsOnly) {
                shutdownManager.initiateShutdown(0);
            }
        };
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {R2dbcAutoConfiguration.class})
@Configuration
@EnableRetry
public class MainApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```